# Can you Animate like in Stop Motion Animation?

Tags: animation, sculpting

In Stop Motion Animation, the proccess is very simple, you have a piece of clay (or something else) and you tweak/remodel it after every frame.

Is there a workflow in blender, that lets you resculpt your model and move it, without rigging it, that is still practical?

For example like the transformation from bruce banner into hulk, while walking.

Comment: Only shape keys come to mind, it could work maybe, but you will need a shape key for every frame (!), it depends on what you mean by "practical"... for your target result, bones rigging + maybe some shape key ( to morph the walking body) is the right choice (even if you set a keyframe per frame...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do can be done using [shape keys](https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/shape_keys/introduction.html). There are many tutorials on Youtube this is one of them [Shape Keys Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gDZcmAWL2jA)

Answer (score 1):

There's an experimental feature still in development (when this answer was written) called `Keymesh` It seems to be way more flexible than shape keys, you can see the proof of concept in [this video](https://vimeo.com/379550189).

[image]